# Phonegap Touch Event Handling

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am trying to make a calculator using phonegap - but I am running into problems in adding the touch event. It does not show anything on the display. kindly see if there are problems in the code. and suggest me a solution. 
**I have added the `onTouch` event to all the numbers and math operators buttons.

```
function onload(){
        document.getElementById("display").addEventListener('onTouch',insert,false);
        document.getElementById("clear").addEventListener('onClear', clear, false);
        document.getElementById("equal")addEventListener('onEqual', evaluate,false);
    }

function clear(){
    document.getElementById("display").value="";
    return false;
}
function insert(val){
    document.getElementById("display").value+=val;
}
function evaluate(){
    try
    {
        ans= eval(document.getElementById("display").value);
        document.getElementById("display")=ans;
        return false;
    }
    catch
    {
        document.getElementById("display").value="Error";
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about the `onTouch` event. Does that exist at all?

I would suggest to try either `touchstart` or `touchend` maybe `touchmove` event handlers. These should work. For example:

```
document.getElementById("display").addEventListener('touchstart',insert,false);
```